# How can I add minutes to given timestamp based on my previous row value in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe

```
   +----------+----------+---------------------+
   | Activity | Interval |    ReadDateTime     |
   +----------+----------+---------------------+
   |    A     |    1     | 2019-12-13 10:00:00 | 
   |    A     |    2     | 2019-12-13 10:00:00 |
   |    A     |    3     | 2019-12-13 10:00:00 |
   |    B     |    1     | 2019-12-13 11:00:00 | 
   |    B     |    2     | 2019-12-13 11:00:00 |
   |    B     |    3     | 2019-12-13 11:00:00 |
   +--------- +----------+---------------------+
```

Now I have to add 5 minute to the ReadDateTime column based on the value present in previous row. My expected dataframe looks like below

```
   +----------+----------+---------------------+
   | Activity | Interval |    ReadDateTime     |
   +----------+----------+---------------------+
   |    A     |    1     | 2019-12-13 10:00:00 | 
   |    A     |    2     | 2019-12-13 10:05:00 |
   |    A     |    3     | 2019-12-13 10:10:00 |
   |    B     |    1     | 2019-12-13 11:00:00 | 
   |    B     |    2     | 2019-12-13 11:05:00 |
   |    B     |    3     | 2019-12-13 11:10:00 |
   +--------- +----------+---------------------+
```

I will not add 5 minutes to ReadDateTime column corresponding to Interval 1 whereas i will keep on adding 5 minutes to the other rows until my activity changes

Comment: Show us what you have tried!

Comment: You cant, you need to extract the dataframe to objects, change them, then save to the dataframe using overwrite

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans I Have figured out the solution and I have posted it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out the solution thanks to the post by Ali Yesilli
[Adding hours to timestamp in pyspark dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093187/adding-hours-to-timestamp-in-pyspark-dynamically).

I have first converted my ReadDateTime into unix timestamp and adding 5 minutes to it only when my Interval is not equal to 1. So my code looks like below.

```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import *

   df = df.withColumn("ReadDateTime1", when(col("Interval") != lit(1),
   col("ReadDateTime") + 
   (col("Interval")*expr("Interval 5 minutes"))).otherwise(col('ReadDateTime')))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly approach

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def update(interval,date):
  if (interval == 1):
    return date
  elif (interval == 2):
    return date + 'add 5 min'
  elif (interval == 3):
    return date + 'add 10 min'

#df.dtypes

my_udf = udf(lambda x,y: update(x,y), StringType())

df.withColumn('updated_realDateTime', my_udf(df.interval, df.realDateTime) ).show(truncate=False)
```

Of couse my update function isnt what u want, so u will have to change it, but it will get the job done (u dont need the elifs if the pattern is the same for all intervals, u can make it dynamic)

here is the code to create the dataframe for anyone with a better answer

```
data = [ (1,'2019-12-13 10:00:00'), 
   (2, '2019-12-13 10:00:00'),
   (3, '2019-12-13 10:00:00'),
   (1, '2019-12-13 11:00:00'), 
   (2, '2019-12-13 11:00:00'),
   (3, '2019-12-13 11:00:00')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ['interval','realDateTime']).cache()
```

Comment: Hi @Benoit, FYI you don't need an udf for this

Comment: Hi @Benoit I can't use this solution as I have 288 Intervals for each activity and I have 10K of such. It will work but won't be efficient. I have posted a simple solution without using UDF. Please have a look at it