# How to add hours as variable to timestamp in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Dataframe schema is like this:
["id", "t_create", "hours"]
string, timestamp, int

Sample data is like:
["abc", "2022-07-01 12:23:21.343998", 5]

I want to add hours to the t_create and get a new column t_update: "2022-07-01 17:23:21.343998"

Here is my code:

```
df_cols = ["id", "t_create", "hour"]
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("blablah path")
df = df.withColumn("t_update", df.t_create + expr(f"INTERVAL 5 HOURS"))
```

It works no problem. However the hours column should be a variable. I did not figure out how to put the variable to the expr, f string and the INTERVAL function, something like:

```
df = df.withColumn("t_update", df.t_create + expr(f"INTERVAL {df.hours} HOURS"))
df = df.withColumn("t_update", df.t_create + expr(f"INTERVAL {col(df.hours)} HOURS"))
```

etc... They don't work. Need help here.

Another way is to write a udf and wrap the whole expr string to the udf return value:

```
@udf
def udf_interval(hours):
    return "INTERVAL " + str(hours) + " HOURS"
```

Then:

```
df = df.withColumn("t_update", df.t_create + expr(udf_interval(df.hours)))
```

Now I get TypeError: Column is not iterable.

Stuck. Need help in either the udf or non-udf way. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are trying to get the values from another column. No need of udf. Just follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093187/adding-hours-to-timestamp-in-pyspark-dynamically). Achieved via `unix_timestamp`.

Comment: This works but I think the make_interval solution below is more like a fix to my original solution that uses INTERVAL. And actually the time precision is in microseconds and the unix_timestamp function only gives second level precision. It should not be hard to solve but adding a bit complexity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without using the fiddly `unix_timestamp` and utilise [make_interval](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview2/api/sql/index.html#make_interval) within SparkSQL

#### SparkSQL - TO_TIMESTAMP & MAKE_INTERVAL

```
sql.sql("""
WITH INP AS (
SELECT
    "abc" as id,
    TO_TIMESTAMP("2022-07-01 12:23:21.343998","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS") as t_create,
    5 as t_hour
)

SELECT 
    id,
    t_create,
    t_hour,
    t_create + MAKE_INTERVAL(0,0,0,0,t_hour,0,0) HOURS as t_update
FROM INP 
""").show(truncate=False)

+---+--------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|id |t_create                  |t_hour|t_update                  |
+---+--------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|abc|2022-07-01 12:23:21.343998|5     |2022-07-01 17:23:21.343998|
+---+--------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

#### Pyspark API

```
s = StringIO("""
id,t_create,t_hour
abc,2022-07-01 12:23:21.343998,5
"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)\
             .withColumn('t_create'
                            ,F.to_timestamp(F.col('t_create')                   
                                ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'
                            )
             ).withColumn('t_update'
                            ,F.expr('t_create + MAKE_INTERVAL(0,0,0,0,t_hour,0,0) HOURS')                   
             ).show(truncate=False)

+---+--------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|id |t_create                  |t_hour|t_update                  |
+---+--------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|abc|2022-07-01 12:23:21.343998|5     |2022-07-01 17:23:21.343998|
+---+--------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to cast the timestamp to `bigint` (or `decimal` if dealing with fraction of second) and add the number of seconds to it. Here's an example where I've created columns for every calculation for detailed understanding - you can merge all the calculations into a single column.

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([("2022-07-01 12:23:21.343998",)]).toDF(['ts_str']). \
    withColumn('ts', func.col('ts_str').cast('timestamp')). \
    withColumn('hours_to_add', func.lit(5)). \
    withColumn('ts_as_decimal', func.col('ts').cast('decimal(20, 10)')). \
    withColumn('seconds_to_add_as_decimal', 
               func.col('hours_to_add').cast('decimal(20, 10)') * 3600
               ). \
    withColumn('new_ts_as_decimal', 
               func.col('ts_as_decimal') + func.col('seconds_to_add_as_decimal')
               ). \
    withColumn('new_ts', func.col('new_ts_as_decimal').cast('timestamp')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +--------------------------+--------------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
# |ts_str                    |ts                        |hours_to_add|ts_as_decimal        |seconds_to_add_as_decimal|new_ts_as_decimal    |new_ts                    |
# +--------------------------+--------------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
# |2022-07-01 12:23:21.343998|2022-07-01 12:23:21.343998|5           |1656678201.3439980000|18000.0000000000         |1656696201.3439980000|2022-07-01 17:23:21.343998|
# +--------------------------+--------------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
```